# WPF- TimePicker is not updating

Tags: c#, wpf, timepicker, toolkit

I'm using Time Picker from wpfToolkit.extended in WPF application.

When I select a time in the dropdrownlist everything works the way it should. This is the namespace of the toolkit.

```
xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
```

This is the xaml for the timepicker

```
<Controls:MetroWindow 
    x:Class="TimeSheet.DayView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:e="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:l="clr-namespace:TimeSheet.Views.DataTemplateSpace"
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
    xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
    x:Name="MainWin"
    Title="DayView" Width="596" Height="596">

<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colours.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/Blue.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseLight.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

       <!-- <Style x:Key="ColoringStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
            <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="ListBoxItem_MouseDoubleClick"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding isSynced}" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gold"></Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding isSynced}" Value="false">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Aqua"></Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>-->

        <!-- Default DataTemplate -->
        <DataTemplate x:Key="DefaultDataTemplate" >
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="596">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ClientNameBinding}" Background="Transparent" Padding="0" Margin="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="145"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ApplicationNameBinding}" Background="Transparent" Padding="0" Margin="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="90"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding StartTimeBinding}" Background="Transparent" Padding="0" Margin="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="100"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding StopTimeBinding}" Background="Transparent" Padding="0" Margin="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="60"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding TaskNameBinding}" Background="Transparent" Padding="0" Margin="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="71"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ProjectNameBinding}" Background="Transparent" Padding="0" Margin="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="130"/>  
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>

        <!-- Editable DataTemplate -->
        <DataTemplate x:Key="EditableDataTemplate">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="596">
                <!--<ComboBox x:Name="ClientComboBox" SelectionChanged="ClientComboBoxChanged" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=clientList, ElementName=MainWin}" SelectedValuePath="_id" DisplayMemberPath="_name" SelectedItem="{Binding ClientNameBindingClass, Mode=OneWayToSource}" Background="Yellow" Padding="0" Margin="0" BorderThickness="0" Width="145"/>-->
                <TextBox Text="{Binding ClientNameBinding,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Background="Yellow" Padding="0" Margin="0" BorderThickness="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="145"/>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding ApplicationNameBinding}" Background="Yellow" Padding="0" Margin="0" BorderThickness="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="90"/>
                <xctk:TimePicker Name="StartPicker" TextBoxBase.TextChanged="StartPicker_TextChanged" Value="{Binding StartValue, ElementName=MainWin, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Format="Custom" FormatString="hh:mm tt" Background="Yellow" Padding="0" Margin="0" BorderThickness="0" Width="100" EndTime="11:59:0"/>
                <xctk:TimePicker Name="EndPicker" TextBoxBase.TextChanged="EndPicker_TextChanged" Value="{Binding EndValue, ElementName=MainWin, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Format="Custom" FormatString="hh:mm tt" Background="Yellow" Padding="0" Margin="0" BorderThickness="0" Width="60" EndTime="11:59:0"/>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding TaskNameBinding}" Background="Yellow" Padding="0" Margin="0" BorderThickness="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="71"/>
                <ComboBox x:Name="ProjectComboBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=projectList, ElementName=MainWin}" SelectedValuePath="_id" DisplayMemberPath="_name"  SelectedItem="{Binding ProjectNameBindingClass, Mode=OneWayToSource}" Width="130" Background="Yellow" BorderThickness="0"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>


        <!-- DataTemplate Selector -->

        <l:DayViewListDataTemplateSelector x:Key="templateSelector"
          DefaultDataTemplate="{StaticResource DefaultDataTemplate}"
          EditableDataTemplate="{StaticResource EditableDataTemplate}"/>

    </ResourceDictionary>

</Window.Resources>


  <Viewbox Stretch="Fill" Width="{Binding Width, ElementName=MainWin}" Height="{Binding Height, ElementName=MainWin}">
    <Grid Margin="0,0,0,-4" Background="#FF3399FF" Height="557">

        <Button x:Name="BackButton" Style="{DynamicResource MetroCircleButtonStyle}"  Content="&lt;---" Foreground="Blue" Click="BackButton_Click" Margin="7,2,524,491"/>
        <Button x:Name="TimerButton" Width="124" Height="46" Click="TimerButton_Click" Margin="172,12,300,499">
            <Button.Background>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF5B6CB8"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Button.Background>
        </Button>
        <Label x:Name="monthLabel" Content="May" RenderTransformOrigin="2.34,0.545" FontFamily="Times New Roman" FontSize="20" Margin="431,2,90,522"/>
        <Label x:Name="dayDateLabel" Content="Friday, 27" RenderTransformOrigin="0.446,0.226" FontFamily="Times New Roman" FontSize="36" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="376,35,38,467"/>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="-1,93,1,434" RenderTransformOrigin="1.155,0.47" Height="25">
            <TextBox Text="Client" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Width="145" Foreground="White" Background="Blue" Padding="0" BorderThickness="0" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
            <TextBox Text="Application" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Width="90" Foreground="White" Background="Blue" Padding="0" BorderThickness="0" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
            <TextBox Text="StartTime" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Canvas.Left="148" Canvas.Top="86" Width="100" Foreground="White" Background="Blue" Padding="0" BorderThickness="0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
            <TextBox Text="StopTime" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Width="60" RenderTransformOrigin="0.471,0.692" Foreground="White" Background="Blue" Padding="0" BorderThickness="0" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
            <TextBox Text="Task" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Canvas.Left="378" Canvas.Top="86" Width="130" Foreground="White" Background="Blue" Padding="0" BorderThickness="0" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
            <TextBox Text="Project" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Width="71" Foreground="White" Background="Blue" Padding="0" BorderThickness="0" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <ListBox x:Name="listBox1" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="0,131,0,59" ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource templateSelector}" SelectionMode="Single">
            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                    <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="listBox1_MouseDoubleClick">
                    </EventSetter>
                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ListBox>

        <Button x:Name="SyncEntry" Content="Sync All" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="476,498,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="95" Click="SyncEntry_Click">
            <Button.Background>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF5256AC"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Button.Background>
        </Button>
        <Button x:Name="EditButton" Content="Edit" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="393,498,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="EditButton_Click">
            <Button.Background>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF5256AC"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Button.Background>
        </Button>
        <Button x:Name="CustomButton" Content="Add" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,70,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" FontSize="12" Height="20" FontWeight="Normal" Click="CustomButton_Click"/>
    </Grid>
</Viewbox>
```

I've seen solution for this  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14895507/timepicker-updatesourcetrigger-propertychanged-doesnt-change-value)

but when I write C# code-

```
public partial class DayView : MetroWindow, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private DateTime currentDateForWindow;

    public List<Harvest_Project> projectList{get;set;}

    public List<Harvest_Client> clientList {get; set;}

    public Harvest_Project selectedProjectid {get; set;}

    public Harvest_Client selectedClientid {get; set;}

    public string ElementName { get; set; }

    public DateTime StartValue { get; set; }

    public DateTime EndValue { get; set; }

    public DayView(DateTime s)
    {
            InitializeComponent();
             this.DataContext = this;

            Globals._globalController.setDayViewWindow(this);

            currentDateForWindow = s;

            dayDateLabel.Content = s.DayOfWeek + ", " + s.Day;
            monthLabel.Content = s.ToString("MMMM");

            if(Globals._globalController.win32Manager.isTimerRunning)
                TimerButton.Content = "Stop";
            else
                TimerButton.Content = "Start";

            listBox1.Items.Clear();

            listBox1.MouseDoubleClick += new MouseButtonEventHandler(listBox1_MouseDoubleClick);
            clientList = Globals._globalController.harvestManager._CLIENTLIST;
            projectList = Globals._globalController.harvestManager._PROJECTLIST;
            Globals._globalController.fetchAndPopulateForDate(currentDateForWindow);

            Globals.ni2 = new NotifyIcon();
            Globals.ni2.Icon = TimeSheet.Properties.Resources.DayViewIcon;
            Globals.ni2.Visible = true;
            Globals.ni2.Click +=
            delegate(object sender, EventArgs args)
            {
                this.Show();
                this.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;

            };

     }

    protected override void OnStateChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (WindowState == System.Windows.WindowState.Minimized)
        {
            this.Hide();
            Globals.ni2.BalloonTipTitle = "DayView";
            Globals.ni2.BalloonTipText = "This is Day window";
            Globals.ni2.Visible = true;
            Globals.ni2.ShowBalloonTip(500);
            base.OnStateChanged(e);
        }
    }

    public void addHarvestEntrytoView(Harvest_TimeSheetEntry entry)
    {

          listBox1.Items.Add(entry);

    }

    public void addHarvestEntrytoView(List<Harvest_TimeSheetEntry> entry)
    {
        foreach (Harvest_TimeSheetEntry x in entry)
            listBox1.Items.Add(x);
    }

    private void BackButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
            Globals.ni2.Visible=false;
            this.Hide();
            Globals._globalController.getMonthViewWindow.Show();
            Globals.ni1.Visible = true;
    }

    private void TimerButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Globals._globalController.win32Manager.isTimerRunning)
        {
            Globals._globalController.win32Manager.startTimer();
            this.TimerButton.Content = "Stop";
        }
        else
        {
            Globals._globalController.win32Manager.stopTimer();
            this.TimerButton.Content = "Start";
        }
    }


    private void SyncEntry_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Submit All unsynced Entries

        foreach(Harvest_TimeSheetEntry item in listBox1.Items)
       {
           if (!item.isSynced)
           {
               if (item.ProjectNameBinding == "Select Project" && item.ClientNameBinding == "Select Client")
                   System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Please select you Project and Client");
               else
               //Check if something is selected in selectedProjectItem For that item
               Globals._globalController.harvestManager.postHarvestEntry(item);
               System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Entry posted");
           }
       }

    }



    private void listBox1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        //Submit clicked Entry
        if (sender is ListBoxItem)
        {
            ListBoxItem item = (ListBoxItem)sender;
            Harvest_TimeSheetEntry entryToPost = (Harvest_TimeSheetEntry)item.DataContext;

            if (!entryToPost.isSynced)
            {
                //Check if something is selected in selectedClientItem and selectedProjectItem For that items
                if (entryToPost.ClientNameBinding == "Select Client" || entryToPost.ProjectNameBinding == "Select Project")
                    System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Please select you Project and Client");
                else
                {
                    Globals._globalController.harvestManager.postHarvestEntry(entryToPost);
                    System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Entry posted");
                    DataTemplate tmpl = (DataTemplate)this.FindResource("DefaultDataTemplate");
                    listBox1.ItemTemplate = tmpl;
                }
            }
            else
            {

                //Already synced.. Make a noise or something
                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Already Synced;TODO Play a Sound Instead");
            }
        }


     }

    private void EditButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Harvest_TimeSheetEntry item in listBox1.Items)
        {
            if (item.isSynced)
            {
                item.isSynced = false;
                listBox1.ItemTemplate = (DataTemplate)this.FindResource("EditableDataTemplate");
                this.EditButton.Content = "Done Editing";
            }
            else
            {
                listBox1.ItemTemplate = (DataTemplate)this.FindResource("DefaultDataTemplate");
                this.EditButton.Content = "Edit";
                Globals._globalController.harvestManager.postHarvestEntry(item);
                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Entry posted");
            }
        }
    }

    private void CustomButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Globals.ni2.Visible=false;
        CustomView c = new CustomView(Globals._globalController.getDayViewWindow);
        c.Show();
        this.Hide();
        Globals.ni3.Visible = true;
    }

    private void StartPicker_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        StartPicker.Focus();
    }

    private void EndPicker_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        EndPicker.Focus();
    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(String time)
    {
        if (System.String.IsNullOrEmpty(time))
        {
            return;
        }
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(time));
        }
    }


    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    #endregion

}
```

It shows error as "StartPicker and EndPicker does not exist in current context".

Suggest the ways to solve this error.

Comment: Where have you written the two methods in? They should be written in the code behind file of the corresponding XAML file.

Comment: Yes. These methods are written in code behind of corresponding xaml file.

Comment: Can you show some more code of your xaml.cs

Comment: I bound these to simple DateTime objects in my xaml.cs

Comment: But your error is coming that StartPicker and Endpickerdoesnt exist..How can is this possible when they both are written behind code

Comment: It's confirm that I've return code in my code behind. My xaml is DayView.xaml and Code behind is DayView.xaml.cs

Comment: show your complete xaml and xaml.cs code

Comment: See Now, I've uploaded full code.

Comment: Your problem is that you can't access members which are inside a template.

Comment: so, Any other way to update time?

Comment: @user2622971 is your question answered? if yes, could you please accept the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Xaml-

```
    <Grid>
            <xctk:TimePicker Name="StartPicker" TextBoxBase.TextChanged="StartPicker_TextChanged" Value="{Binding StartTimeBinding, ElementName=MainWin, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Format="Custom" FormatString="hh:mm tt" Background="Yellow" Padding="0" Margin="0" BorderThickness="0" Width="100" Height="50" EndTime="11:59:0"/>

            <xctk:TimePicker Name="EndPicker" TextBoxBase.TextChanged="EndPicker_TextChanged" Value="{Binding StopTimeBinding, ElementName=MainWin1, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Format="Custom" FormatString="hh:mm tt" Background="Yellow" Padding="0" Margin="0" BorderThickness="0" Width="60" Height="50" EndTime="11:59:0"/>          

    </Grid>
```

Code-Behind your Xaml in Xaml.cs

```
private void EndPicker_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            StartPicker.Focus(); // shows error at TimePicker Name(i.e StartPicker)
        }

        private void StartPicker_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            EndPicker.Focus();  // shows error at EndPicker
        }
```

Comment: Same thing, which I did.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
private void StartPicker_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    TimePicker tp = sender as TimePicker;
    if(tp != null)
    {
        tp.Focus();
    }
}

private void EndPicker_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    TimePicker tp = sender as TimePicker;
    if(tp != null)
    {
        tp.Focus();
    }
}
```

Of course you can have only one function and point from both timepickers to this function:

```
private void TimePicker_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    TimePicker tp = sender as TimePicker;
    if(tp != null)
    {
        tp.Focus();
    }
}
```

and then in the xaml:

```
<xctk:TimePicker Name="StartPicker" TextBoxBase.TextChanged="TimePicker_TextChanged" Value="{Binding StartValue, ElementName=MainWin, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Format="Custom" FormatString="hh:mm tt" Background="Yellow" Padding="0" Margin="0" BorderThickness="0" Width="100" EndTime="11:59:0"/>
<xctk:TimePicker Name="EndPicker" TextBoxBase.TextChanged="TimePicker_TextChanged" Value="{Binding EndValue, ElementName=MainWin, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Format="Custom" FormatString="hh:mm tt" Background="Yellow" Padding="0" Margin="0" BorderThickness="0" Width="60" EndTime="11:59:0"/>
```