# WPF toolkit TimePicker value not changing on time manual entry but fires when focus changed

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, wpftoolkit

I am using `WPF toolkit TimePicker`

```
<xctk:TimePicker Name="timePicker" 
                 StartTime="{Binding MpStartTime,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  
                 EndTime="{Binding MpEndTime,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"    
                 TextBoxBase.TextChanged="TimePicker_TextChanged"
                 Value="{Binding ResTime,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode="TwoWay"}"
                 Format="Custom" 
                 FormatString="hh:mm tt"/>
```

The problem is when I enter time manually with the numpad the `PropertyChanged` is not firing, and the time is not updating in the View model.

The actual problem is the value does not update until the focus is lost, so when I add the following line:

```
private void TimePicker_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
        timePicker.Focus();
}
```

The value seems to change, but now I can't type anything in the time picker as the focus is lost whenever the text is changed. Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: Change the UpdateSoruceTrigger to `LostFocus` so that as soon as you move the focus out of TimePicker then trigger will fire.

Comment: Is `sender` and `timePicker` the same `TextBox`?

Comment: @user1672994 no That I've tried it is not working.

Comment: @Sinatr `sender` is the `TimePicker` control

Answer (score 1):

Just for reference, it looks you were using workaround from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14895507/1997232).

You are saying what inside `TimePicker_TextChanged`:

> `sender` is the `TimePicker` control

Ok, so you are setting focus to a wrong control. Or, actually, it works for other guy, because it cause `LostFocus` event for `TextBox` (setting focus to anything else would also do), but not when you want to continue typing value using keyboard.

In WPF custom controls are often composite, so I believe there is a `TextBox` child element somewhere.

You can try following code:

```
void TimePicker_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var textBox = FocusManager.GetFocusedElement(this) as TextBox;
    if (textBox != null)
    {
        textBox.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));
        textBox.Focus();
    }
}
```

The idea is to find child `TextBox`, pass focus somewhere else and then set it back. This should trigger `LostFocus` event of `TextBox` and will work if `TimePicker` uses binding with `UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus` or if it handles `LostFocus` (I don't know how exactly `xctk:TimePicker` works).

---

Another approach would be to alter binding of that `TextBox.Text` to have `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`. That's preferrable way if you can alter control template.

Comment: Thank you for the effort, Now the `TextBox` inside the time picker seems to get focused but somehow I am still not able to type in.